# Is it possible to remove the git working tree?

Tags: git

Is it possible to get a git repository back into the state it was after running `git clone --no-checkout`, i.e. without any files checked out / without having a checked-out working tree?

I’d like to just use different work trees for different features, and have nothing checked out into the root directory.

Comment: Run git clone no checkout again?

Comment: @matt thanks, that’s the fallback option. I would have to setup all remote and tracking info again though.

Comment: @joachim not really – I don’t want a bare repo, but it might be worth an option.